# What countries are already represented in the Bitcoin network?

Tags: network

What countries are already represented in the Bitcoin network?  I am asking this to see a list of countries, so we will know how well it is spreading, and if there is some area that is not reached.  So please, show us where we can find this list:

Comment: I would suggest that you change the question so that it asks where the stats you are looking for can be found, instead of trying to keep and up-to-date list here. The list of countries connected will change a lot, especially at this time when some countries are only represented by a single node, so it does not fit as a question for a StackExchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in Bitcoin nodes, This website seems to keep a count of how many of them are connected by country:

http://bitcoinstatus.rowit.co.uk

Or, if you want more graphical (and cooler looking) data, just look at this globe:

http://www.weusecoins.com/globe-bitcoin/

It shows you what amount of Bitcoin nodes are connected in each geographical area not only at a country level, but going down to what I believe is a city level.

Comment: That is so way cool.  Thank you.  Do you know what the colors represent?

Comment: @shoelessjoe I think the orange ones are IPs that don't belong to a specific place in the country, the green ones might be something similar, but I'm not sure. Blue ones should be nodes with identifiable IPs.

Comment: Second link's not active anymore. Are there any mirrors of it? First's still alive and well.

Comment: Both links are now dead. This answer is no longer useful.

Answer (score 3):

http://bitcoinstatus.rowit.co.uk is a site where you can find such stats. It has (among other stats) a list of countries and the number of connected nodes in that country.

Comment: The link is dead - this answer now contains no useful information.